# How-to redirect nested urls in Node.js + Express

Tags: redirect, node.js, nested, url-routing, express

I'm tryin to do a module that redirect old urls to the new one on Node.JS + Express:

`app.get('/category1', function (req, res){ res.redirect('/category2', 301) })` - works fine.

but when we're goin to `/category1/subcategory` it doesnt redirect to `/category2/subcategory`

How-to do this redirect rule like in apache's .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^category1/(.*)$ category2/$1 [R,NC,L]`

e.g.

`/category1 -> /category2`

`/category1/ -> /category2/`

`/category1/2/3/ -> /category2/2/3/`

`/category1/2/?a=1&b=2 -> /category2/2/?a=1&b=2`

Answer (score 4):

You can't build a route like the following?

```
app.get('/category/*', function(req, res){ 
    res.redirect('/category2/' + req.params[0], 301);
});
```

Edited for wildcard use case.

I'd suggest checking out expressjs.com's section on routing.

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing

Comment: This willn't redirect url like `/category1/subcategory/a/b/c`

Comment: ah, well you didn't say that was the use case. i'll modify the example

Comment: ok, that works, but doesn't identical `^category1/(.*)$ category2/$1`. I've modified use cases in question